# "OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory" when pip freeze using Flask

Tags: flask, pip, freeze, requirements

When I try **pip freeze** (or pip freeze > requirements.txt), I've this error :

```
$ pip freeze
Error [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flaskr-0.0.0-py2.7.egg' while executing command git rev-parse
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/freeze.py", line 86, in run
    for line in freeze(**freeze_kwargs):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/operations/freeze.py", line 50, in freeze
    dependency_links
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 255, in from_dist
    if dist_is_editable(dist) and vcs.get_backend_name(location):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/vcs/__init__.py", line 76, in get_backend_name
    if vc_type.controls_location(location):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/vcs/git.py", line 292, in controls_location
    on_returncode='ignore')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/vcs/__init__.py", line 325, in run_command
    spinner)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 667, in call_subprocess
    cwd=cwd, env=env)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flaskr-0.0.0-py2.7.egg'
```

I've *not* error(s) when I install some package. I don't use virtualenv for the moment.
Have an idea about this error please ?

Thanks.
F.

Answer (score 0):

It was just a problem with Flaskr (I don't know why it was here...)
So, I just do :

```
sudo pip uninstall Flaskr
```

And, it's done.